# How to perform performance testing on Citrix Workspace

Tags: testing, performance-testing, citrix

In order to access the developed software, we can log in via Citrix Workspace and open a browser, and in this way we can access the address.I couldn't find a very detailed document on performance testing on Citrix with Jmeter. I wonder if anyone knows a tool where I can perform these performance tests and has detailed information about this tool?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it using JMeter however you will need a special [plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CitrixPlugin#jmeter-citrix-plugin),here is a "very detailed" [user manual](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CitrixPlugin/blob/master/MANUAL.md#user-manual) explaining the steps you need to take.

See [NEW! JMeter Citrix Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/new-jmeter-citrix-plugin) article for more information if needed.